# Why is root path of child module is loaded on root path of parent module?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

Here is my application's setup:

```
   app.module
    |
   layout.component
        |
------------------------------------------
|             |        |                  |
feature1.module    contract.module    feature2.module
                      |
                ----------------
                        |
               contract-details.module 
                        |
             --------------------------
             |                         |
       component1                 component2
```

Here `contract.module` and `contract-details.module` are lazy loaded modules. 
Now, when I navigate to root path i.e `{path: "" ... }`of `contract.module` I should get `ContractComponent`'s template but instead I am getting `contract-details.module`'s `ContractDetailsComponent`'s template loaded.
Here are my routes:
`contract.module.ts`:

```
const CONTRACT_ROUTE = [
  {path: "", component: ContractComponent,

  children: [

    {path: "main",component: ContractComponent},
    {path: "details",loadChildren: "../contract-details/contract-details.module#ContractDetailsModule"},
    {path: "",redirectTo: "main",pathMatch: 'full'},
    ]

 },

  ];
```

`contract-details.module.ts`

```
const CONTRACT_DETAILS_ROUTE = [
   { path: "",
    children: [
      {path: "test",component: ContractDetailsComponent},
      {path: "tempComponent",component: TempComponent},
      {path: "",redirectTo: "test",pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
  }  
];
```

Can anyone point out my mistake here.

Also, I tried moving contract-details module a level up i.e along side contract.module but then there is a `router-outlet` inside `contract-details.component.html` which display the templates of the component's route which again does not render in contract-details's router outlet instead it's rendering in parent router-outlet.
Here the template code:

```
      <ul>
        <li> <a [routerLink] = "'tempComponent'">temp1</a></li>
        <li> temp 2</li>
        <li> temp 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Can you include your code usages of `CONTRACT_ROUTE` and `CONTRACT_DETAILS_ROUTE` in your modules? i.e. are you using `RouterModule.forRoot` or `RouterModule.forChild`?

Comment: Both are used as `RouterModule.forChild`, just the route of Lazy loading contract along with Home and other core modules are included in `RouterModule.forRoot`